# Are there lockers on the beaches of Tel Aviv?

Tags: security, israel, beaches, tel-aviv

I would like to go swimming without being afraid of leaving valuables out in the open. Are there secure lockers at Tell Aviv beach where I can leave my stuff? If so, where are they located?

Comment: Did you try a Google search for "Tel Aviv beach lockers"? What's wrong with the options given at https://www.tripadvisor.co.nz/ShowTopic-g293984-i3332-k7803553-Beach_with_lockers-Tel_Aviv_Tel_Aviv_District.html or https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293984-i3332-k6707790-Experience_with_lockers_at_tel_Aviv_beach_are_they_safe-Tel_Aviv_Tel_Aviv_District.html? Are you only interested in lockers at freely accessible beaches or also in beaches you have to pay for?

Comment: @martin.koeberl all of Tel Aviv's beaches are free. The TripAdvisor pages only mention two lockers and don't mention their exact location. I think there should be an official page listing this.

Comment: This will be hard. The municipality of Tel Aviv runs the beaches now and  the [Aviv beach page](https://www.tel-aviv.gov.il/Visitors/Beaches/Pages/Aviv.aspx) for example provides a link to תאי שמירת חפצים  (luggage storage, I guess) but only a picture is given not a location. You can easily switch https://gisn.tel-aviv.gov.il/iview2js/index.aspx to English but I can't see lockers as an option.

Comment: As of last week, Manta Ray has lockers, and I suspect that most of the other mentioned beaches have those as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this 2015 Ynet article (Hebrew)](http://www.ynet.co.il/articles/0,7340,L-4648875,00.html), Lockers were placed in most Tel Aviv beaches.

A locker is opened with a 10 ILS coin, which is not returned.

The official visit-tlv site has a [beaches section in Hebrew](http://www.visit-tlv.co.il/?CategoryID=195), which says which beaches have lockers. The lists differs from Ynet's, and I don't know which is correct.

Beaches which have lockers according to either list:

- [Hatzuk](https://www.google.ie/maps/place/HaTsuk+Beach/@32.1416455,34.7856982,16z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1shatzuk+beach+tel+aviv!3m4!1s0x151d4924ca5ca06f:0x62012c659f359f8b!8m2!3d32.1416678!4d34.7905777), Ynet and visit-tlv.
- [Metzizim](https://www.google.ie/maps/place/Metzitzim+Beach/@32.0904302,34.758203,13z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sbeach+tel+aviv!3m4!1s0x151d4c74d3ca4049:0x55e0c155e20e7c48!8m2!3d32.0937096!4d34.7709346), Ynet.
- [Nordau Segragated](https://www.google.ie/maps/place/Nordau+Segregated+Beach/@32.0930378,34.768587,17z/data=!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x151d4c74e79b7af9:0x37105bf95cfb26ee!2sNordau+Segregated+Beach!8m2!3d32.0930378!4d34.7707757!3m4!1s0x151d4c74e79b7af9:0x37105bf95cfb26ee!8m2!3d32.0930378!4d34.7707757) (religious), Ynet and visit-tlv.
- [Manra Ray](https://www.google.ie/maps/place/Manta+Ray/@32.061312,34.7577167,17z/data=!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x151d48f2805ae943:0xd1ae2698e2d1065c!2sManta+Ray!8m2!3d32.061312!4d34.7599054!3m4!1s0x151d48f2805ae943:0xd1ae2698e2d1065c!8m2!3d32.061312!4d34.7599054), Ynet, verified by @kirilsolo on 08/2017.
- [Surfers](https://www.google.ie/maps/place/Hilton+Beach/@32.0898968,34.7646543,16z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sHilton+Beach!3m4!1s0x151d4c7402458dfd:0x1637692b89d82cb4!8m2!3d32.0903272!4d34.7694044) (Hilton), Ynet.
- [Jerusalem](https://www.google.ie/maps/place/Jerusalem+Beach/@32.0847786,34.762963,14.71z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sbeach+tel+aviv!3m4!1s0x151d4c87b5053cef:0xd89a79488947426f!8m2!3d32.0737338!4d34.7644007), Ynet and visit-tlv.
- [Frishman](https://www.google.ie/maps/place/Frishman+Beach/@32.0844112,34.762133,15.1z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sbeach+tel+aviv!3m4!1s0x0:0x7c6dea16f5d7560d!8m2!3d32.0800224!4d34.7667825), Ynet.
- [Bograshov](https://www.google.ie/maps/place/Bograshov+Beach/@32.0783657,34.7640896,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x151d4b7c393bb6d9:0xfe5d21f99b0a6229!8m2!3d32.0783657!4d34.7662783) - visit-tlv.
- [Banana Beach](https://www.google.ie/maps/place/Banana+Beach/@32.0705236,34.7613458,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x151d49248698aceb:0x7a30829cb3ed8de2!8m2!3d32.0705236!4d34.7635345) - Ynet
- [Givat Aliya](https://www.google.ie/maps/place/%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A3+%D7%92%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%AA+%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%99%D7%94%E2%80%AD/@32.0392944,34.7427772,17z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x1502b333e68fb46f:0x30891c171d4ffd29!2sGivat+Aliya+Beach!3b1!8m2!3d32.0389571!4d34.7453701!3m4!1s0x0:0xa825f6185b9fb5bb!8m2!3d32.0393067!4d34.7452296) (in Jaffa) - Ynet.